# Akka.NET AwaitAssert not working when there are many tests

Tags: unit-testing, xunit, akka.net, nsubstitute, event-driven

I'm using [Akka.NET](http://getakka.net/) together with [NSubstitute](http://nsubstitute.github.io/) and [XUnit](https://xunit.github.io/). I have a `ReceiveActor` which listens to quite a lot events. And it seems that when I try to test the logic for these events they start crasching if I have too many tests. It works fine in the "real world", but when I have too many tests for the events it seems to fail. I managed to re-create it with a MCE.

Here's my actor:

```
public class SomeActor : ReceiveActor
{
    private readonly IService service;

    public class BaseEvent
    {
        public Guid Id = Guid.NewGuid();
    }

    public class EventOne : BaseEvent { }
    public class EventTwo : BaseEvent { }
    public class EventThree : BaseEvent { }
    public class EventFour : BaseEvent { }
    public class EventFive : BaseEvent { }
    public class EventSix : BaseEvent { }
    public class EventSeven : BaseEvent  { }
    public class EventEigth : BaseEvent { }
    public class EventNine : BaseEvent { }
    public class EventTen : BaseEvent { }
    public class EventEleven : BaseEvent { }
    public class EventTwelve : BaseEvent { }
    public class EventThirteen : BaseEvent { }
    public class EventFourteen : BaseEvent { }
    public class EventFifteen : BaseEvent { }
    public class EventSixteen : BaseEvent { }
    public class EventSeventeen : BaseEvent { }
    public class EventEighteen : BaseEvent { }
    public class EventNineTeen : BaseEvent { }
    public class EventTwenty : BaseEvent { }

    public SomeActor(IService service)
    {
        this.service = service;
        Become(Ready);
    }

    protected void Ready()
    {
        ReceiveAsync<EventOne>(async msg => await DoStuff(msg));
        ReceiveAsync<EventTwo>(async msg => await DoStuff(msg));
        ReceiveAsync<EventThree>(async msg => await DoStuff(msg));
        ReceiveAsync<EventFour>(async msg => await DoStuff(msg));
        ReceiveAsync<EventFive>(async msg => await DoStuff(msg));
        ReceiveAsync<EventSix>(async msg => await DoStuff(msg));
        ReceiveAsync<EventSeven>(async msg => await DoStuff(msg));
        ReceiveAsync<EventEigth>(async msg => await DoStuff(msg));
        ReceiveAsync<EventNine>(async msg => await DoStuff(msg));
        ReceiveAsync<EventTen>(async msg => await DoStuff(msg));
        ReceiveAsync<EventEleven>(async msg => await DoStuff(msg));
        ReceiveAsync<EventTwelve>(async msg => await DoStuff(msg));
        ReceiveAsync<EventThirteen>(async msg => await DoStuff(msg));
        ReceiveAsync<EventFourteen>(async msg => await DoStuff(msg));
        ReceiveAsync<EventFifteen>(async msg => await DoStuff(msg));
        ReceiveAsync<EventSixteen>(async msg => await DoStuff(msg));
        ReceiveAsync<EventSeventeen>(async msg => await DoStuff(msg));
        ReceiveAsync<EventEighteen>(async msg => await DoStuff(msg));
        ReceiveAsync<EventNineTeen>(async msg => await DoStuff(msg));
        ReceiveAsync<EventTwenty>(async msg => await DoStuff(msg));
    }

    private async Task DoStuff(BaseEvent arg)
    {
        await service.DoOtherStuff(arg.Id);
        await service.DoOneThing();
        await service.DoAnotherThing(arg.Id);
        await service.DoAThing();
    }
}
```

Then I created a test class for this actor.

```
public abstract class ActorTestBase : TestKit
{
    private void TestEvent(SomeActor.BaseEvent msg)
    {
        var service = Substitute.For<IService>();
        var actor = Sys.ActorOf(Props.Create(() => new SomeActor(service)));
        actor.Tell(msg);
        AwaitAssert(() =>
        {
            service.Received().DoOtherStuff(Arg.Is<Guid>( x => x == msg.Id));
            service.Received().DoAnotherThing(Arg.Is<Guid>(x => x == msg.Id));
            service.Received().DoOneThing();
            service.Received().DoAThing();
        });
    }

    [Fact]
    public void ShouldCallDoOtherStuffWhenReceiveEventOne()
    {
        TestEvent(new SomeActor.EventOne());
    }

    [Fact]
    public void ShouldCallDoOtherStuffWhenReceiveEventTwo()
    {
        TestEvent(new SomeActor.EventTwo());
    }

    // ....
    // Other facts for the remaining 18 events exists as well...
    // ....

}
```

This works fine. All events are received and handled. But when I run the tests with several implementations of `ActorTestBase` (simply to try to recreate my actual situation) the tests starts to fail. The more tests I run at the same time the more tests fail. If I run them one at the time they always work.

```
public class FirstActorTests : ActorTestBase    {   }

public class SecondActorTests : ActorTestBase   {   }

public class ThirdActorTests : ActorTestBase    {   }
```

I cannot say when it starts to fail, but somewhere around 100-150 tests. It's not the same test that fails every time. My best guess is that it has something to do with the logic in [`AwaitAssert`](http://api.getakka.net/docs/stable/html/C6A1034F.htm), but I cannot figure it out. I know that the current tests aren't that good, but it's simply an example to recreate the issue.

Comment: Could you please post a stack trace or error message you get.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. There is no Exception. The test fails. It's Nsubstitute saying that the methods didn't get received.